# Database Issue - An error occurred while executing the command definition. See the inner exception for details

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, entity-framework, t-sql

Trying to populate lists from my database as follows, here is the controller:

```
namespace TimetableSystem.Controllers
{
public class AvailabilityController : Controller
{
    TimetableSystemEntities systemDB = new TimetableSystemEntities();

    public ActionResult Index()
    {

        var parkList = new List<String>();
        var parkQry = from p in systemDB.Parks
                      orderby p.ParkID
                      select p.ParkName;
        parkList.AddRange(parkQry);
        ViewBag.Park = parkList;
```

here is the park model:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace TimetableSystem.Models
{
    public class ParkModel
    {
        [Key]
        public int ParkID { get; set; }
        public string ParkName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

and here is the TimetableSystemEntities model:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace TimetableSystem.Models
{
    public class TimetableSystemEntities : DbContext
    {
        public TimetableSystemEntities() : base("DefaultConnection") { }

        public DbSet<Department> Departments { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Module> Modules { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Request> Requests { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Round> Rounds { get; set; }
        public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
        public DbSet<ParkModel> Parks { get; set; }
        public DbSet<BuildingModel> Buildings { get; set; }
        public DbSet<RoomModel> Rooms { get; set; }
    }
}
```

But when I debug and move to the Availability page, I am given this error:

[System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException]
{"Invalid object name 'dbo.ParkModels'."}

Not sure what is happening here as I can't find 'ParkModels' anywhere in the project or the database, the model is ParkModel, the database table is Park.

Comment: Change `DbSet<ParkModel>` to DbSet<Park>

Comment: Thank you but that just changes the error to **{"Invalid object name 'dbo.Parks'."}**

Comment: This is one of those questions that would benefit from [accepting an answer by the community](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3669/would-it-be-possible-to-have-a-community-accepted-feature).

Comment: I think, you will need add migration for your Context and update database. If you are using EF6 for connection database, this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/ef/ef6/modeling/code-first/migrations/?redirectedfrom=MSDN) help you

Answer (score 1):

My understanding of code-first is that by convention the model and table names need to match. In your case they don't so you need to specify the mapping.

```
[Table("Park")]
public class ParkModel
{
    [Key]
    public int ParkID { get; set; }
    public string ParkName { get; set; }
}
```

Then your context should be:

```
DbSet<ParkModel> Parks { get; set; }
```

Comment: This post is fairly old, so don't know if someone will even see this, but...actually, the code-first convention is not that the model and table names match. It's that the model is the singular of the table name. i.e., model = 'Park' and table = 'Parks'. But, yes, you are correct that when the convention is not followed, you have to specify the table name.